# Synchronising/Uploading a .csv file from Google Drive to Google Drive Bucket using Cloud Shell Commands

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I have a csv file in my google drive.

I'm trying to take it to a google cloud bucket using cloud shell commands.

Anyone can help please?!

Thanks ^-^

Comment: Potentially you could use the Google Drive REST API (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) to download your csv file to the machine performing the call, and then from there using either the Cloud Storage APIs, the Python SDK, or the gsutil commands, upload it to the bucket of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no a “direct” way to accomplish this, however, there are many workarounds to make this with some extra steps. You could even write and deploy a program on GAE or GCE to do this . But I think the easy way to do this would be download the file to your local machine (with Cloud SDK installed previously) and then upload it with gsutil command [1]:

Input into google cloud shell or your terminal if google cloud sdk is installed:

```
gsutil cp myfile.csv gs://my-bucket
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp